# Creating List Items with related Terms

Tags: taxonomy, list-item, term

I'm trying to create a List Item, but is not clear to me how to provide the TermGuid.

I've tried something like this:

```python
payload = {
    "fields": {
         "Title": "My item",
         "CustomMetadataField": {
              "TermGuid": "[uuid]"
         }
    }

}
```

But I always get a 400 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to add should be the same as the method to update.  See link below. Note that if it's a multi-value metadata field, you'll need to use a different method, basically adding the item first, and then updating it with the term set value.

```
await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Demo").items.add({
    Title: "My item",
    CustomMetadataField: { Label: "YourTermLabel", TermGuid: '883e4c81-e8f9-4f19-b90b-6ab805c9f626', WssId: '-1' }
});
```

Reference: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#update-taxonomy-field
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#update-multi-value-taxonomy-field

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem but might get me into the right direction.  I'm not using any libraries so I need the HTTP equivalent.